# Error during kafka rolling upgrade 2.0 to 3.6

Tags: apache-kafka

We are trying to do a rolling upgrade of kafka from 2.0 to 3.6 , during the upgrade faced the below error until all the brokers are upgraded

`org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidRequestException: Error getting request for apiKey: FETCH, apiVersion: 12`

During the error the brokers are not able to connect to the leader and it has under replicated partitions. Is there a way to overcome this issue.